# Не могу подключиться к БД из docker compose

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, docker, docker-compose

Мое bakend приложение запускается командой `py manage.py runserver`, frontend запускается командой `npm run dev`, ошибок при этом не возникает, подключение к БД работает.

Однако при запуске команды
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml  --env-file=academy/.env up`
я получаю ошибку
(Моя БД при этом находится не в контейнере, а на 127.0.0.1:5432):

```
(venv) PS C:\PycharmProjects\DjangoProjects\academy-server> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml  --env-file=academy/.env up
[+] Running 2/1
[+] Running 2/3emy-server_default       Created                                                                                                                                                                                    0.8s 
[+] Running 2/3emy-server_default       Created                                                                                                                                                                                    0.8s
[+] Running 2/3emy-server_default       Created                                                                                                                                                                                    0.8s 
[+] Running 2/3emy-server_default       Created                                                                                                                                                                                    0.8s
[+] Running 2/3emy-server_default       Created                                                                                                                                                                                    0.8s
[+] Running 2/3emy-server_default       Created                                                                                                                                                                                    0.8s
[+] Running 2/3emy-server_default       Created                                                                                                                                                                                    0.8s
[+] Running 2/3emy-server_default       Created                                                                                                                                                                                    0.8s
[+] Running 2/3emy-server_default       Created                                                                                                                                                                                    0.8s
[+] Running 3/3emy-server_default       Created                                                                                                                                                                                    0.8s
 - Network academy-server_default       Created                                                                                                                                                                                    0.8s
 - Container academy-server-academy-1   Created                                                                                                                                                                                    0.1s
 - Container academy-server-frontend-1  Created                                                                                                                                                                                    0.9s
Attaching to academy-server-academy-1, academy-server-frontend-1
academy-server-frontend-1  | 
academy-server-frontend-1  | > frontend@0.0.0 dev
academy-server-frontend-1  | > vite
academy-server-frontend-1  |
academy-server-frontend-1  | 
academy-server-frontend-1  |   VITE v4.4.8  ready in 1006 ms
academy-server-frontend-1  |
academy-server-frontend-1  |   ➜  Local:   http://localhost:8000/
academy-server-frontend-1  |   ➜  Network: http://172.23.0.3:8000/
academy-server-academy-1   | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
academy-server-academy-1   | Performing system checks...
academy-server-academy-1   |
academy-server-academy-1   | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
academy-server-academy-1   | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
academy-server-academy-1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
academy-server-academy-1   |     self.connect()
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
academy-server-academy-1   |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
academy-server-academy-1   |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
academy-server-academy-1   |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 269, in get_new_connection
academy-server-academy-1   |     connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
academy-server-academy-1   |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
academy-server-academy-1   | psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
academy-server-academy-1   |    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
academy-server-academy-1   |
academy-server-academy-1   |
academy-server-academy-1   | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
academy-server-academy-1   |
academy-server-academy-1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
academy-server-academy-1   |     self.run()
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 917, in run
academy-server-academy-1   |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
academy-server-academy-1   |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 136, in inner_run
academy-server-academy-1   |     self.check_migrations()
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 574, in check_migrations
academy-server-academy-1   |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
academy-server-academy-1   |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
academy-server-academy-1   |     self.build_graph()
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
academy-server-academy-1   |     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
academy-server-academy-1   |     if self.has_table():
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
academy-server-academy-1   |     with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
academy-server-academy-1   |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 330, in cursor
academy-server-academy-1   |     return self._cursor()
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 306, in _cursor
academy-server-academy-1   |     self.ensure_connection()
academy-server-academy-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
academy-server-academy-1   | django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
academy-server-academy-1   |    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

**Мой файл `docker-compose.yaml` выглядит следующим образом:**

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    environment:
      WDS_SOCKET_PORT: 3000

    ports:
      - ${FRONTEND_EXPOSE_PORT}:3000

    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app/frontend
      - /app/frontend/node_modules

    depends_on:
      - academy

    # Сеть
    networks:
      - myNetwork

    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

    env_file:
      - academy/.env

  academy:
    build:
      context: ./academy
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_HOST: 'host.docker.internal'
      POSTGRES_PORT: ${DB_PORT}

    ports:
      - ${DJANGO_EXPOSE_PORT}:8000
      - ${DB_PORT}:5432

    volumes:
      - ./academy:/app/academy

    # Сеть
    networks:
      - myNetwork

    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

    env_file:
      - academy/.env

# создаём сеть.
networks:
  myNetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

**Docerfile backend:**

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app/academy

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

COPY requirements.txt /app/academy/
COPY . /app/academy/

RUN apt update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev &&  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "manage.py"]
CMD ["runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

**Я использую Vite.
Мой Docerfile frontend:**

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app/frontend

COPY package*.json /app/frontend/

RUN npm install

RUN npm i -g react-scripts

COPY . /app/frontend/

RUN chown -R node /app/frontend/node_modules

USER node

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Для тестирования я запускать `docker` на `windows`, но в дальнейшем запускать буду на `linux`.

**settings.py**

```
# Database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': env('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': env('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': env('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': env('DB_PORT'),
    }
}
```

**.env**

```
DEBUG=True

# PostgreSQL Database
DB_NAME=Academy_Base
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432

# Frontend
FRONTEND_EXPOSE_PORT=3000

# Backend
DJANGO_EXPOSE_PORT=8000
```

В фале **postgresql.conf**, расположенному на `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\data`
установлен параметр:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

В фале **pg_hba.conf**, расположенному на `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\data`
установлено разрешение:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all       all      127.0.0.1/32       scram-sha-256
```